# Grouping in an array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have 2 javascript array objects of the following format:

```
 var input1 = 
    {
      "a" : [
       {
         "id" : 1,
         "name" : "gh"
       }],
      "b" : [
       {
         "id" : 2,
         "name" : "ab"
       }]

    }

var input2 =
{
 "a" : [
       {
         "id" : 3,
         "name" : "cd"
       }],
       "b" : [
       {
         "id" : 4,
         "name" : "gh"
       }]
}
```

I am looking to format it in the following way :

```
var finaloutput = 
    {
      "a" : [
       {
         "id" : 1,
         "name" : "gh"
       },
        {
         "id" : 3,
         "name" : "cd"
       }
        ],
      "b" : [
       {
         "id" : 2,
         "name" : "ab"
       },
       {
         "id" : 4,
         "name" : "gh"
       }
      ]      
    }
```

I am trying to group the array without using any external libraries. Not very much familiar with linq in javascript , any built in functions available or any references?

Edit: I made the changes in the inputs since this is what I am expecting as inputs

Comment: Your first block doesn't hold what you think it does, the first `"a"`,`"b"` properties are going to be overwritten by the second set. So its just going to be `{ a:[{id:3}], b:[{id:4}] }`

Comment: your object reinitialise the keys.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, of course this is just a quick implemention - but it should set you on the correct path:

```
var finaloutput = Object.keys(input1).reduce((p,v) => {
  p[v] = (input1[v].concat(input2[v]))
  return p;
}, {})
```

returns =>

JSON.stringify(finaloutput, null, 2);

```
"{
  "a": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "gh"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "cd"
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "ab"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "gh"
    }
  ]
}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a map and fill it checking for key existence, with any given number of inputs

```
var allInputs = [];
allInputs.push(input1);
allInputs.push(input2);

var result = [];

for(var x in allInputs)
{
    var inp = allInputs[x];
    for(var i in inp)
    {
        if(result[i] == undefined)
        {
            result[i] = [];
        }

        result[i].push(inp[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var finalOutput;
    var input1 = {
            "a": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "gh"
            }],
            "b": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "ab"
            }]
    };

    var input2 = {
            "a": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "cd"
            }],
            "b": [{
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "gh"
            }]
    };
    input1.a.push(input2.a[0]);
    input1.b.push(input2.b[0]);
    finalOutput = input1;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
    If the arrays are dynamic you can do the operation as follows:

    var input1 = {
        "a": [
          {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "gh"
          }
        ],
        "b": [
          {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "ab"
          }
        ]
}

var input2 = {
        "a": [
          {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "cd"
          }
        ],
        "b": [
          {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "gh"
          }
        ]
}
var inputNewLengthA = input1.a.length;
var inputNewLengthB = input1.b.length;
var finalOutput;
for(var v=0;v<inputNewLengthA;v++){
    input1.a.push(input2.a[v]);
}
for(var n=0;n<inputNewLengthB;n++){
    input1.b.push(input2.b[n]);
}
finalOutput = input1;
///////////////////////////////////////
Note: You can also use one for loop only if your array lengths are   
equal.
```